# flutter: which button from List<Widget> is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have List of TextButton and i dynamicly add and delete them. How to know which index of pressed button? I tried add a key but it doesnt seem to work, i always get -1 as an index. when i tried to use the exact same code as a function inside the HomeScreenState it worked just fine, but when i did it a class, something went wrong.     what am i doing wrong? why isn't it finding the key?

thanks in advance

```
List<String> Titles = [];

List<Widget> active_notes = [];
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}
class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  Widget home_page(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        onPressed: () {
          Titles.add("");
          note_infos.add(NoteInfo());
          addWidgetToColumn(noteCard());},
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: active_notes),
      ),
    );
  }
class noteCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const noteCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  noteCardState createState() => noteCardState();
}

class noteCardState extends State<noteCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toString());
    int index = -1;
    int ind = Titles.length - 1;
    Titles[Titles.length - 1] = "title" + ind.toString();
    return TextButton(
      key: key,
      onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          index = active_notes.indexWhere((e) => e.key == key);
          ind = index;
          //print("index: $index");
          Titles[index] = "title" + index.toString();
          return noteScreenState.note_page(
              context, index); //calling the editing menu
        }));
        String t1 = Titles[ind];
        print("old title: $t1");
        setState(() {
          Titles[ind] = "TITLE" + ind.toString();
        });

        t1 = Titles[ind];
        print("New title: $t1");
      },
child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.label,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              Titles[ind], //make it variable. somehow
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 22,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the index is to use a `ListView.builder` which has an item builder - it will render each widget you provide in the item builder:

In your example, it seems like you'd want to use the `Titles` list. Something like this:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: Titles.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(Titles[index]),
    );
  },
)
```

---

Here is a demo app that shows a snackbar that says which item was pressed:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _data = List.generate(5, (index) => Text("Item $index"));
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: _data[index],
            onTap: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Item $index tapped'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

###### See also

- [Working with long lists (Flutter.dev)](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)